# adding a selected functionality to divs on click in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to recreate the facebook messenger UI where there's a list of users on the left and upon clicking, their message on the left side becomes "selected" (takes on a different backgroundColor), and fetches their messages to be shown on the right side of the page. I can achieve this using vanilla javascript by simply grabbing all the messages elements, adding an onClick event listener that tells it to remove the "selected" class on any message element that may have it, and then add that "selected" class to the message element that was clicked. Then on my css file, I can simply just change the backgroundColor for any classes named "selected".

However, as a new React developer, I am not sure how this can be done. Can anyone point me to the right direction? I am familiar with hooks and how they work, but I don't know where to start. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

My idea is to maybe handle the backgroundcolor changes when a particular message log is selected, but I don't know how to communicate it back to the parent that a different message log is clicked, thereby removing the message log selected before in order to show that a new message log is selected.

Comment: Hi there @tudk,

I don't use Facebook can you please post the screen recording of what you are trying to do, Maybe I can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useState hook to store the selected id in, like

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState()
```

Then, `onClick` of the div you would call the `setSelected` function with the new id. That way you can access the `selected` id.

Then you can conditionally add the css class to the selected div and display the content of the selected message.

Comment: A variant of this ended up working for me! I just wrapped the component that I was using in a div so that I can add an onClick property to it, and I set a new id within this parent component so that it re-renders the messages and passes on a new selected id. Within the message components, I made it so that if the message id === selected id, then change the background color to appear selected. Thank you!